# Are there any prebuilt simple search engine using Solr?

Tags: solr

New to Solr in general. I have to build a simple search engine web page that utilizes solr. i have already imported data in Solr and i can query like normal using Solr admin. I have no constraints on which language to use.

I'm looking for an already existing library i can adapt to my data similar to the [Ajax Solr demo site](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr) that i tried to make work to no avail.

I tried searching for more but couldn't find anything and make it work, could someone more experienced point me towards more libraries like it, or maybe a tutorial to get Ajax Solr to run on my data?

Comment: [The Velocity Search UI](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/velocity-search-ui.html) is part of the core.

Comment: There is [Banana by lucidworks](https://github.com/lucidworks/banana) this is a port of Kibana.

Comment: Or are you looking for the client APIs? They are described in [the reference](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/introduction-to-client-apis.html). They exist for Java, JavaScript, Python and Ruby.